# LDAPS - No Cipher Suites In Common

Tags: ssl, encryption, ldap

Attempting to authenticate Oracle DBusers via an OUD server (LDAPS)

Receiving the below error upon trying to connect to sql:
[10/Apr/2019:10:42:10 -0500] CONNECT conn=1348 from=xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx to=xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx  protocol=LDAPS
[10/Apr/2019:10:42:10 -0500] DISCONNECT conn=1348 reason="I/O Error" msg="no cipher suites in common"

I've allowed all cipher suites in the Oracle Wallet for the database, and imported the cert from the OUD server.  Allowed plenty of cipher suites on the LDAPS connection handler in OUD via ODSM.  The sqlnet.ora and ldap.ora are all in order.  Not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: This can mean that the server couldn't find a private key so it can only use the anonymous cipher suites, which are usually disabled at both ends.

Comment: The "no cipher suites in common" error is a generic one and doesn't always detail the real issue. If you are using recent Java 8 updates, you may have hit a change where JNDI verifies that the server certificates matches the hostname that the client tries to connect to.
The issue and the solution are documented in the JDK’s release notes: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html#JDK-8200666

Comment: @LudovicPoitou 'No cipher suites in common' isn't a generic error. It is specific to the condition it states, which has nothing to do with hostnames. It does have several ultimate causes, such as the one I mentioned, but hostname mismatch is certainly not one of them. Hostname mismatch would be detected prior to this condition arising.

Comment: I agree but in my experience, the Java layer generally reports "No cipher suites in common" for too many reasons. The best option is to enable SSL debugging to get more in depth messages and a better understanding of where is the error.